# If a plane contains one line and intersects another one elsewhere, then the two lines are not coplanar

Tags: geometry, 3d

The straight line $a$ lies in the plane $\alpha$ , the straight line $b$ intersects $\alpha$ in point $M$. If $M$ doesn't belong to the $a$ prove that there isn't plane which contains the two straight lines.

I don't have idea how to prove this, I thought about proving that the two lines have six dots, that aren't the same but firstly I don't have any idea how to do that and secondly, even if I prove this I will just prove that there are two planes which contain both lines and aren't the same one plane.

Comment: The title should describe the problem as clearly as possible. Also, _proof_ is a noun, the verb you wanted is _prove_.

Comment: Thank you, for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say a plane $\beta$ contained both $a$ and $b$. $\beta$ would contain both $a$ and $M$. But $M \not\in a$, so $\beta$ must coincide with $\alpha$. (There is a *unique* plane through any given line and point not on it.) Since $\alpha$ does not contain $b$, we have a contradiction.